# rpy2 LD_LIBRARY_PATH conflict

Tags: linux, odbc, netezza, rpy2

I have faced a problem with a conflict between two libraries in linux ubunto. I am using Netezza `ODBC` driver and I have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable as following 

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/m/nz/lib64'`

and that library works. then When I want to use `rpy2` library if I set this variable I'll face this error

```
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m/PycharmProjects/sandbox/pyodbcsample.py", line 22, in <module>
    DGGRID_PACKAGE= importr("dggridR")
  File "/home/m/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 453, in importr
    env = _get_namespace(rname)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/m/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2: symbol k5_buf_free version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference
```

When I do not set this environment variable `rpy2` loads with no problem but on the other hand that `odbc` driver stops working.

It is obvious that The problem is with this system environment, I tried to add this string as system environemnt but still it does not work

`{$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/lib:/home/m/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5:/lib:/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/:/home/m/nzClient/linux64/driver/lib64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib64/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

I also tried to add those library path into this file `sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf` to avoid setting `ld_library_path` but again It does not work.

What options do I have to fix this conflict.

Comment: I would start here with adding `LD_DEBUG=all` to the process environment and looking for the problematic symbol in the linker log in both scenarios (with `LD_DEBUG` the linker will generate pretty much output about what and how it does). From which `so` the problematic symbol is loaded in case of success? Does it differ from the failing case?

Comment: I think in current message it says the problamatic part is with gdal.so but is there any options to avoid Ld_library_path? For example copying those folders content to a linux directory with global access?